# Click on submit button which does not have an id using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, scrape

I have tried to click on the submit button using on submit function but I can't see the result. The website I am trying to scrape is

[Jntuh](http://results.jntuh.ac.in/jsp/SearchResult.jsp?degree=btech&examCode=1442&etype=r17&type=intgrade)

The submit button has the following properties

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I have used this `.execute` script

```
Resultbrowser.execute_script("""document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit();""")
```

I dont know if the website has an on submit function

Entire code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

link = 'http://results.jntuh.ac.in/jsp/SearchResult.jsp?degree=btech&examCode=1442&etype=r17&type=intgrade'
hallticket = "1780XXXXXX"
dobval = '1998-03-01'
with webdriver.Chrome() as Resultbrowser:

    Resultbrowser.get(link)
    Hallfield = Resultbrowser.find_element_by_name("htno")
    Hallfield.send_keys(hallticket)
    Hallfield.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    dob = Resultbrowser.find_element_by_class_name('hasDatepicker')
    dob.send_keys(dobval)
    dob.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    dob.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    time.sleep(2)
    Resultbrowser.execute_script("""
    document.querySelector("#txtInput").value = document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value
    """)
    time.sleep(5)
    Resultbrowser.execute_script("""document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit();""")

    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Locate the entire form-element by its `id`, which is `myForm`, and submit it using the `.submit`-method:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

link = 'http://results.jntuh.ac.in/jsp/SearchResult.jsp?degree=btech&examCode=1442&etype=r17&type=intgrade'
hallticket = "1780XXXXXX"
dobval = '1998-03-01'
with webdriver.Chrome() as Resultbrowser:

    Resultbrowser.get(link)
    Hallfield = Resultbrowser.find_element_by_name("htno")
    Hallfield.send_keys(hallticket)
    Hallfield.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    dob = Resultbrowser.find_element_by_class_name('hasDatepicker')
    dob.send_keys(dobval)
    dob.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    dob.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    time.sleep(2)
    Resultbrowser.execute_script("""
    document.querySelector("#txtInput").value = document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value
    """)
    time.sleep(5)

    form = Resultbrowser.find_element_by_id("myForm")
    form.submit()

    time.sleep(10)
```

or using the `.execute_script`-method that you already wrote:

```py
Resultbrowser.execute_script("""document.getElementById("myForm").submit();""")
```

i.e. replace `onsubmit` with `submit`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, whats the best possible way to store the result in an mysql database , how can i achive it, should i use xpath to gather data and how can i learn what possible option do i have, docs, links would be helpful

Comment: @Arshad No problem. For your second question I would probably start by parsing the tables of the resulting page with `pandas.read_html`. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-scraping-html-tables-with-pandas-and-beautifulsoup-7fc24c331cf7) page seems to provide a helpful guide. For the MySQL part you should open another question to provide further details.